# How to lead logging in Mysql after delete/update actions?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

`events` and `visitors`

Admin can delete any row from both tables, how to logging this actions?

Is it a good practice to create additionally two tables:

`events_log` and `visitors_log` and fill these tables using triggers DELETE/UPDATE?

I want to know who did action, at which time, and have ability to recovery touched row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways of doing this and approach is generally related with content of your data, and context. If your intention is to know which user did what and you are not interested with what was the old data, then It may be enough to have one history table for all your tables rather than having separate log table for each table which is needed to be logged.